# Pi Calculator output issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have created a simple python program that calculates pi by counting the number of 1 pixel points that fit in a circle. At first I ran the program with the following values:

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_oval(100,100,400,400)

global pi_count
pi_count = 0

for x in range(100,400):
    for y in range(100,400):
        point = canvas.create_oval(x,y,(x+1),(y+1))
        c = canvas.coords(point)
        sc = list(c)
        xc = sc[1]
        yc = sc[2]
        fxc = int(xc)
        fyc = int(yc)
        dist = ((fxc - 250)**2 + (fyc - 250)**2)**0.5
        if dist > 150:
            print("outside of the circle")
        else:
            pi_count += 1
        print(pi_count)

pi = (pi_count/150**2)
print(pi)
```

This gave me the output 3.1412888889.

Relatively pleased with this result, I changed the oval dimensions to 
`(100,100,500,500)`
and changed all other values(radius, for loops etc.) accordingly.

However this larger circle and presumably more accurate area produced a more inaccurate estimate of 3.140675.

Why is this, and how can I fix the calculator to give more accurate estimates?

**EDIT**

Here is edited and improved code that is easier to test:

```
from tkinter import *

MIN_POS = 100
MAX_POS = 300
center = (MAX_POS + MIN_POS)/2
radius = (MAX_POS - MIN_POS)/2

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=MAX_POS, height=MAX_POS)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_oval(MIN_POS,MIN_POS,MAX_POS,MAX_POS)

global pi_count
pi_count = 0

for x in range(MIN_POS,MAX_POS):
    for y in range(MIN_POS,MAX_POS):
        point = canvas.create_oval(x,y,(x+1),(y+1))
        c = canvas.coords(point)
        sc = list(c)
        xc = sc[1]
        yc = sc[2]
        fxc = int(xc)
        fyc = int(yc)
        dist = ((fxc - center)**2 + (fyc - center)**2)**0.5
        if dist > radius:
            print("outside of the circle")
        else:
            pi_count += 1
        print(pi_count)

pi = (pi_count/radius**2)
print(pi)
```

I would appreciate it if anyone with a fast computer can run this program with `Max_pos` being raised in steps of 100.

Comment: Large data set (larger circle)?

Comment: Did you change every occurence of `400` to `500`? Magic numbers like this are dangerous, use a named constant. Odds are you only changed part of the `400`s.

Comment: The same goes for `250` which presumably comes from `(100+400)/2`.

Comment: I have definitely changed all the numbers, and have changed back and forth as a test as well as have friends proof read.

Comment: Do you mind running the code to see what happens? @AndrasDeak

Comment: I just did, and you're right. I'd still suggest switching to named constants, especially since changing that one parameter is crucial to your question.

Comment: Yes @AndrasDeak, I intended to do that originally, after testing it with the aforementioned values.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, how long did this take for you to run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164899/discussion-between-andras-deak-and-3141).

Comment: You might want to check the chat @AndrasDeak

Comment: Your 'faster' code would be so much faster if you don't display the points. The calculation itself can be done in memory.

Comment: Sorry @usr2564301, those are for debugging, I should have removed them earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This method is very inaccurate. The results from testing one radius can be quite a lot more or less accurate than 1 less or more:

```
100 -> 3.141700 ~ 1.000034
125 -> 3.140928 ~ 0.999788
150 -> 3.141378 ~ 0.999932
175 -> 3.141518 ~ 0.999976
200 -> 3.140725 ~ 0.999724
225 -> 3.141393 ~ 0.999936
250 -> 3.141136 ~ 0.999855
275 -> 3.140826 ~ 0.999756
300 -> 3.141078 ~ 0.999836
325 -> 3.141311 ~ 0.999910
350 -> 3.140939 ~ 0.999792
375 -> 3.141582 ~ 0.999997
400 -> 3.141406 ~ 0.999941
```

The reason is that you are testing integral values only, and so these tend to round down. While increasing the radius does improve accuracy, it should be impossible to get π with enough decimals until you cross the limits of Python's float accuracy itself – I have no idea how large the radius would need to be for that.

For your value 150, testing 149 and 151 as well shows neither are 'better'; *both* are much worse!

```
150 -> 3.141378 ~ 0.999932
 -1 -> 3.140804 ~ 0.999749
 +1 -> 3.140783 ~ 0.999742
```

Even for a very large radius such as 10,000, you still get 3.141591 ~ 0.999999 (that took a while to calculate).

Tested with the following code (without using the graphical display). Note there is a tiny bug in your code, which also influences the result! You run a range from `(100,400)`, which you might as well write as `(0,300)`. Subtracting the radius, you have `(-150,150)` – but Python's `range` function runs from [`start` to *less than* `stop`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#range). That means you are calculating `-150..-1`, then `0`, then `1..149`, and there is a small bias to the left.

(However, taking that into account does not visibly improve the accuracy.)

```
import math

def calc_pi(radius):
    pi_count = 0
    rad2 = radius*radius
    for x in range(-radius,radius+1):
        x2 = x*x
        for y in range(-radius,radius+1):
            dist = x2 + y*y
            if dist <= rad2:
                pi_count += 1
    return float(pi_count)/radius**2

for i in range(100,401,25):
    result = calc_pi(i)
    print("%d -> %f ~ %f" % (i, result, result/math.pi))
```

Comment: I have edited the post with updated code @usr2564301